# Classes keep getting instantiated - calling a function from the same class - a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, class

Here is my code:

```
// CNet.h
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
class CNet
{
    public:
        CNet();
        ~CNet();
        void FlushDNS();
        LONG DNSFunction1();

    private:
        typedef BOOL(WINAPI* DFRC)();
        DFRC DnsFlushResolverCache{};
        HMODULE hDll = nullptr;
};
CNet::CNet()
{
    hDll = LoadLibrary(L"DnsApi.dll");
    if (hDll)
        DnsFlushResolverCache = (DFRC) GetProcAddress(hDll, "DnsFlushResolverCache");
}

// CNet.cpp
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
void CNet::FlushDNS()
{  
    if (DnsFlushResolverCache)
        DnsFlushResolverCache();    
}  
LONG DNSFunction1()
{
    CNet clsCNet{};  // <- have to create a new class every time DNSFunction1 is called
    clsCNet.FlushDNS();
}
CNet::~CNet()
{
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
```

I need to call FlushDNS from various DNS functions. `DNSFunction1` is just an example.

The problem is, each time I want to call one of the public DNS functions in the `CNet` class like `DNSFunction1`, i.e. from `main()`, the `DNSFunction1` instantiates a new `CNet`. So it ends up running `LoadLibrary` every time I call `DNSFunction1`.

How can I configure this so it's not so inefficient?

Comment: LONG DNSFunction1() is not a public DNS function.

Comment: That fixed it! Ty!

Answer (score 0):

As @S.M. mentioned, changing `LONG DNSFunction1()` to `CNet::LONG DNSFunction1()` solved it.